# Get Oldest Message in the Azure Service Bus Subscription?

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there a way to get the oldest queued message in a subscription without iterating over all the messages and using getEnqueuedTimeUTC? The problem with this approach is that if you don't complete the message, same message will pop back at the top of the queue. Basically I will be in an infinite loop.

How do I find the oldest message in subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first message enqueued will be the first available for processing (assuming it wasn't scheduled). Peeking the queue using `PeekAsync()` method of the queue or subscription clients will give you that message's information, including the time it was enqueued.

Comment: Dear @SeanFeldman, what happened to good old concept of FIFO in Queues? If my application starts reading messages with PEEK mode (or RECEIVEANDELETE shouldn't matter), the first message that my application gets, should be the oldest message (the very first message that got queued). Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not following. Queues are always FIFO. If you haven't completed the message within `MacxLockDuration` time, the message will be available again and it will be processed by another computing consumer right away. The message will **not** go back to the end of the queue. The way I understood your issue and the question is that you wanted to ensure that first message has to be processed _prior_ to any following message. I.e. are you are looking for an order? If that's what you after, Message Sessions feature is what you can use to ensure order. But then the receiver cannot be scaled out.

Comment: I understand that another listener could have hold of the oldest message, and if processing fails, that same message could be put back in the active queue with delivery count incremented.

Comment: I just want to get message enqueue time. I don't want to process them at at.  The idea is to find the oldest message in the queue without processing the message. No operations. So, by FIFO logic, the first message that arrives to my application is the oldest (and unprocessed and no other listener has a hold on this message's lock) message in the queue?

Comment: First message to arrive will be the one first to be processed (assuming it wasn't scheduled). Peeking the queue would give you that message's information you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Sean. Can you please update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done. The world peace and trust in queueing is restored 

Comment: One edge case I do have to mention is scheduling. You could have first message scheduled in future, making it the oldest, but peeking won't work as the message when becomes available will be at the end of the queue. Given it's such an edge case, probably nothing to worry about, but had to mention.

Comment: Thank you Sean. There is nothing scheduled in the queue that I am working in.

Comment: Thank you Sean. Can you please tell me one more time in my English that.... lets say there are 3 entities: 2 applications and 1 queue. Out of 2 applications, 1 is producer that places messages in the queue. And 2nd application is the consumer that reads messages from the queue. And 3rd entity is the Queue itself. Lets say consumer application is down for 10 hours. Meanwhile, producer application continuous to put messages in the queue. Consumer application just came up. It sees 10,000 messages in the queue.

Comment: Now, the very first message that my consumer application reads is the oldest message right?

Comment: Correct. If the first message sent is m1 and last one is Mn, when the consumer is back online, when the queue is peeked, m1 is the message on "top" of the queue.

Comment: Not related, but careful with the term "entity". Azure service bus is using the term to describe queues, topics, and subscriptions. Might become confusing if used interchangeably.

Comment: @seanfeldman The detailed conversation regarding the oldest message retrieval made things easy for me to understand. This should be the final question: Will this peeking concept still retrieve the "oldest" message when I simply peeked a "SESSION or PARTITIONED queue" for the very first time? (Assume I am the only consumer, and I don't use any session related sdk functions such as AcceptSession, but a simple client connection to the queue)

Comment: You always get the messages that were enqueued first.